# How to use Enrichment Nodes in Thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard

How to use Enrichment Nodes in Thingsboard, 
I tried Customer, Device, Related Attributes Node but couldnt able to get that data on metadata. Cany you help me to figure it out.

Screenshot:

**Rule Node:**

[image: Rule Node]

**Related Attribute details:**

[image: Related Attribute details]

**Transform Script:**

[image: Transform Script]

Answer (score 1):

I got my device attributes using originator attributes Enrichment Node in ThingsBoard

Answer (score 1):

thank you for answer, I have successfully fetched server attributes of my device. Here are some materials how I did it for someone in the future:

Images:

[Part of rule chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwhLN.png)
[Enrichment - originator attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BGyk.png)

Script testing: (stackoverflow is trowing me some errors for not properly formatting code, so go on this): https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Cwi.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/na1LK.png

Code from script (comments are in Croatian language if you wish to translate them):

```js
//metadata.ImpFor_delta_hour je povjesna varijabla
//msg.ImpFor_delta_hour je upravo izracunati satna delta od ImpFor-a

if (typeof metadata.ImpFor_delta_5 !== 'undefined' && typeof metadata.ss_delta_ImpFor_min !== 'undefined' && typeof metadata.ss_delta_ImpFor_max !== 'undefined') { //ako nam nije dostavljen povjesni podatak ili nisu definirane granice

    //ImpFor_delta_hour dolazi u obliku \"17\" (tocno s tim znakovima, nisam nista dodao)
    var HIST_ImpFor = metadata.ImpFor_delta_5; //mozda nepotrebno, ali lakse je za raditi s varijablom
    HIST_ImpFor = HIST_ImpFor.replace(/\"/g, ''); //micemo visak oko broja
    HIST_ImpFor = parseInt(HIST_ImpFor); //string->integer
    
    //po povjesnoj vrijednosti se stvaraju granice
    var histDGranica = HIST_ImpFor * (metadata.ss_delta_ImpFor_min/100); //granice se definiraju za svaki node individualno u njihovim server atributes
    var histGGranica = HIST_ImpFor * (metadata.ss_delta_ImpFor_max/100); //granice su deinirane kao % u server atributes, ali nam ovdje treba /100 (55%/100=0.55)
    
    if (msg.ImpFor_delta_5 > histDGranica && msg.ImpFor_delta_5 < histGGranica){ //da li je nova delta unutar granica
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}else{
    return true; //ako nemamo povjesnog podatka ne mozemo procjeniti da li je ili nije unutar granica pa nema smisla dizati alarm
}
//throw new Error(HIST_ImpFor); //ako zelis isprintati neku variablu u error popup
```